# Picaso Run out of memory when load more then 100 image

Tags: android, picasso

I have used Picaso for my android project but when I load more image with more then 100 image it display run out of memory.

How to solve that problems here is my java

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
       .load(album.getGrid_item_image())
       .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_img)
       .error(R.drawable.ic_action_no_image)
       .resize(450, 350)
       .centerCrop()
       .into(holder.grid_item_image);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why once load more than 100 images? Did you use ListView or RecyclerView? If not, of course it display run out of memory.

Comment: I use Recyclerview and I implement load more + 25 every scroll to the bottom.